# Processing GET requests with XML responses

Tags: python, xml, curl, get, wget

I currently export data manually however need to automate the process.

Using Fiddler the set of actions that occur are as follows.

How do i automate it below using wget, cURL, python or PERL?

The date and time is in epoch standard.

GET request

```
Archive.cgi?cmd=check_dst&start_time=1400889660&end_time=1400975940&cam=255&username=QkFCWVo=&rnd=6798
```

It returns the following XML response

```
<result>4</result>
```

The next request is

```
Archive.cgi?cmd=query&cam=255&start_time=1400889660&end_time=1400975940&dst=2&level=0&username=QkFCWVo=&rnd=6825
```

With the XML response

```
<Archive_Query><result>1</result><Size>10100</Size><st>0x537fe086</st><et>0x53808133</et><Stream_num>0</Stream_num></Archive_Query>
```

Followed by the next GET request

```
Archive.cgi?cmd=register_stream&login_id=201442411242611&rnd=1810
```

Which returns the following XML response

```
e6b1a0dc54334bef07e695f5b5640c3a
```

Followed by the final GET request

```
Archive.cgi?cmd=archive_ctrl&action=cancel&stream_id=e6b1a0dc54334bef07e695f5b5640c3a&username=QkFCWVo=&rnd=675
```

Which returns the following XML output

```
<result>1</result>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Python`, I would recommend combining the `requests` library to do the `GET` and get the response data back, and then an `XML Parser` such as ElementTree (https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse the XML.

`requests` handles `JSON` data natively, but for `XML` data needs to be combined with an `XML parser`.

For the timestamp aspect in the URLs look at the `datetime` class and in particular the `strftime` method for formatting timestamps in a specific way and, if you need to dynamically calculate times incrementally (say, every hour or something), the `timedelta` method.

For pure `epoch` time, check out `gmtime()` or `localtime()` functions.

**Edit: In response to OP's comment:**

The `requests` doc. with examples, is here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

There are also examples for `ElementTree` in the link above (https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

`datetime` doc, with examples: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Not a python developer as such but can work with examples. Are there examples i could follow?

Comment: Added more links above which have examples.